# Are there any IntelliJ features to map values between two similar objects?

Tags: java, soap, intellij-idea, integration, pojo

I've been doing a lot of integration towards SOAP services lately. Say I get this object from the SOAP service:

```
public class ObjectA{
  private String someString;
  private Integer someInteger;
}
```

For this object I want to make my own representation "ObjectB" which is basically the same but I dont want to expose objects from the WSDL outside my integration artifact.

So then I map between ObjectA and ObjectB. But this is a lot of manual work especially if the objects have many fields. Are there any smart ways in IntelliJ to generate a mapping between two objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Dozer framework, which is an Object-to-Obejct mapper.

By default it will map by convention, but this can be overridden/customized with a mapping file.

Details here: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/

I've used it before to map use-case specific service payload objects onto re-usable domain objects.

*Edit:*

[MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/) is a more modern mapping framework. It uses compile-time generation:

Comment: It's very slow, so unless you know speed won't be an issue, find something better or do it by hand.